# How do I interpret Python coverage.py branch coverage results?

Tags: python, coverage.py, python-coverage

I'm using `coverage.py` to measure the code coverage of my tests. I've enabled branch coverage, but I can't quite make sense of the report.

Without branch coverage, I get 100% coverage:

```
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------
mylib/queries.py                  44      0   100%
```

With branch coverage enabled:

```
Name                           Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mylib/queries.py                  44      1     20      3    94%   55, 21->10, 53->-48, 59->-58
```

The source in question can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/eykd/1d9cbb50f1cae0873bac05e3a20909ea).

`21->10` makes sense; the `if` clause never evaluates to `False` (jumping back to the beginning of the outer for loop).

However, `53->-48` and `59->-58` have me scratching my head. What do they mean?

Comment: It's probably an empty list inside of that for loop so it never executes the code inside the loop.

Comment: Hm, yeah, the loops always have something to chew on in the test cases I'm providing. So the missing "branch" is the case of an empty set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dan's comment is close.  First, the negative numbers mean, an exit from a function starting at that line number.  So -48 means, exit from the function starting at line 48.

The issue isn't empty loops: those branches would have happened if the loops ever completed.  It looks like perhaps they did not.

BTW: Coverage.py 4.1b3 has changed some of this behavior: they'd be marked as `53->exit, 59->exit`.  Also, the branches themselves might be identified differently.  Give it a try.

Comment: Ned, thanks for taking the time to answer my question, and thanks for this truly useful package.

Comment: The output in 4.1b3 definitely makes more sense, however I'm still confused by `53->exit`; line 53 here is [a for-loop inside a generator function](https://gist.github.com/eykd/1d9cbb50f1cae0873bac05e3a20909ea#file-queries-py-L53) and not really a branch. What am I missing?

Comment: Your for-loop never finishes, so it never naturally exits the function.  I'm not sure what it does do, though.  Perhaps an exception?

Comment: I see. That gives me enough to go on. Thanks again.