# interpretion of branch coverage

Tags: python, coverage.py

This is kind of an followup question to [How do I interpret Python coverage.py branch coverage results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304078/how-do-i-interpret-python-coverage-py-branch-coverage-results)

I have a different situation where I check a variable `perr` which has in different scenarios, which I am testing could be either an empty `List` or a `List[str]`.

The code looks similar to this:

```py
if perr:
    message = self.trim_password_prompt(perr[0])
    if len(message):
        raise SystemError(f"{message}")

return pout
```

Assuming that the if-statement is at line 92 and the return-statement on line 97, the Missing Branch is listed as `92->97`.

I have different if-statements in my code, which are successful tested in multiple tests.

I don't understand after all the things I was reading, why the coverage fails here, since I have tests, which are reaching both lines.

Comment: In your case, `92->97` means "`if` branch not executed, going to next statement directly (condition was false)".

Comment: So far I think I can follow. But why is this marked? I know that in a different test the condition was true. From the standpoint: Why is it here marked, but for my other if statements not?

Answer (score 0):

I read over and over through the documentation of pytest and according articles. I came to the resume the documentation includes no actual information about what branch coverage actually is or link at least to relevant information.

I was at least able to find some further and straight forward informations, which gave me a hint, what branch coverage actually is testing:

[https://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs252/Book/branchcov.html](https://www.cs.odu.edu/%7Ecs252/Book/branchcov.html)

After reading this few lines, I think I understand the issue. pytest could at this point better document this.

Sadly I wasn't able to test my actually code against this knowledge with reasonable effort.

So based on that, I came to the following conclusion:

For some reason, I am unable to control, the value of `perr` never results in false in my tests. Since line 97 is tested nevertheless, the statement testing is completed for all lines, but the jump from line `92->97` has never occurred.

If my statements are correct, I am fine with the result, since mocking is not reasonable from my standpoint.